# How can I configure TeraCopy 3 so that it copies small (< 10 KB) files faster?

Tags: windows, performance, file-transfer, speed, teracopy

TeraCopy 3.6 copies small (< 10 KB) files very slowly (10 files ~= 3 secs):

[image]

I didn't have this issue with TeraCopy 2. How can I configure TeraCopy 3 so that it copies small (< 10 KB) files faster?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that "Failed" was selected. If instead one selects "All files", the copies are >x50 times faster, as shown in the gif below:

[image]

I switched ~10 times between "Failed" and "All files" and I could consistently reproduce this behavior. I think this is a bug.

---

More demo:

[image]